# Chrome css bug - sometimes rendering duplicate form but fixes if the browser resizes

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, ninja-forms

I have a wordpress site and am using the latest ninja forms. I have a minified css file of 240kb and foundation.css in a seperate file of 140kb.

Most prominently if i test the page in Incognito mode, chrome is rending a second form below the original one with hidden fields shown. If i resize the browser it sorts it out.

[image: Example]

**UPDATE**

Ninja forms is loading its own style sheet in the footer rather than the head. Could this be the reason its having layout issues?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Ninja forms was loading the style sheets in the footer. I added this to my own functions file in the "wp_enqueue_scripts" action and it moved the style sheets to the head and resolved the issue.

```
wp_deregister_script( 'ninja-forms-style-display' ); 
wp_deregister_script( 'ninja-forms-display' ); 
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-qtip' ); 
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-rating' ); 
wp_enqueue_style( 'ninja-forms-style-display', NINJA_FORMS_STYLE_URL.'/css/ninja-forms-style-display.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'ninja-forms-display', NINJA_FORMS_URL .'css/ninja-forms-display.css?nf_ver=' . NF_PLUGIN_VERSION );
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-qtip', NINJA_FORMS_URL .'css/qtip.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-rating', NINJA_FORMS_URL .'css/jquery.rating.css' );
```